# JavaScript is Doing a Post on Server Side Twice

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

Student Data Grid that display the student id and a description in the grid. It also has a select button when the user click on it that would route to a javascript function. This function will set some flags on the server side, close the window, past the studentID on a search box and do an automatic search on the studentID. The click appears to be doing exactly what I want it to do. 
However, if the user were to double click on a row in the grid, it is supposed to do the exact same thing. it should also do a post. The double click is doing the post twice. What is causing it to do the post twice? I have not been able to figure it out. I've been putting alert all over the place and no success as to why.

In case you may be wondering why I have the dataroute and a client side script. This grid is in a pop up page that is also being called from other pages. When the user calls the grid from another page, the user will have the ability to select multiple records vs. only being able to select one records when they are calling it from the Course Page.

Here is the Grid:

```
@(Html
    .Telerik()
    .Grid((IEnumerable<OverrideStudent>)SessionWrapper.Student.OtherStudentSelected)
    .Name("StudentData")
    .DataKeys(Keys =>
    {
        Keys.Add(c => c.StudentID);
    })
    .DataBinding(databinding => databinding.Server())
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentId)
            .Title("Student ID")
            .Width(15)
            .Sortable(true)
            .Filterable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentDescription)
            .Title("Description")
            .Width(65)
            .Sortable(true)
            .Filterable(false);
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Custom("AddStudent")
                .Text("Select")
                .DataRouteValues(routes =>
                {
                    routes.Add(o => o.StudentID).RouteKey("StudentID");
                    routes.Add(o => o.StudentDescription).RouteKey("StudentDescription");
                })
                .Action("Student", "StudentInfo");
             .HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "PostData(this);StudentSelectClick(this)" });

        }).Width(20);
    }).ClientEvents(clients => clients
            .OnComplete("OnComplete")
        //.OnDataBinding("DataBinding")
        //.OnDataBound("onRowDataBound")
            .OnRowSelected("StudentDoubleClick")
            )
    .Sortable()
    .Selectable()
    .Filterable(filtering => filtering
                .Enabled(true)
    .Footer(true)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "padding-right: 0.0em;" }))
```

Here are the JavaScripts that are doing the post:

```
function StudentDoubleClick(e) {
        var fromCourse = "@SessionWrapper.Student.FromCoursePage";
        var fromList = "@SessionWrapper.Student.FromListingPage";
        if (fromCourse  == "True") {
            $('tr', this).live('dblclick', function () {
                alert("Inside TR count = " + count);
                count = count + 1;
                DoSearchStudent(e);
            });
        }

        if (fromList == "True") {
            $('tr', this).live('dblclick', function () {
                DoSearchStudent(e);
            });
        }
    }



function DoSearchStudent(e) {
        var row = e.row;
        var StudentID = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
        var StudentDescription = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
        //  alert(procCodeDesc);
        var data = { "StudentID": StudentID, "StudentDescription": StudentDescription, "action": "Double Click" };
        var url = '@Url.Action("Student", "StudentInfo")';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                window.top.location.href = window.top.location.href;
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("An error has occured and the window will not be closed.");

            }
        });
    }


//Single Click on BUtton


 function StudentSelectClick(e) {
        var windows = this.parent.$('#Window').data('tWindow');
        var fromCourse = "@SessionWrapper.Student.FromCoursePage";
        var fromList = "@SessionWrapper.Student.FromListingPage";
        if (fromCourse  == "True") {
            var studentInformation = e.toString();
            var data = { "myModel": "null", "studentInformation": studentInformation };
            var url = '@Url.Action("UpdatedFromSelect", "StudentProcedure")';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    // window.top.location.href = window.top.location.href;
                    windows.close();
                    // setTimeout(this.window.top.location.href =    this.window.top.location.href, 1000);
                    window.top.location.href = window.top.location.href;

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("An error has occured and the window will not be closed.");

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the method where the double is being posted to. It simply redirect to a different method of return type ActionResult that also does a redirect to the index page of return ActionResult:

```
public string Student(string StudentID, string StudentDescription, string action)
        {
            if (StudentDescription != null)
            {
                StudentDescription = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(StudentDescription);
            }

            try
            {
               AddStudent(StudentID, StudentDescription, action);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Error " + e.ToString(); 
            }

            return "Success";
        }
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are perhaps _both_ your `dblclick` handlers firing? If you want them to be exclusive put an `else` in there somewhere.

Comment: iirc double click also does click

Comment: Well, only one of the if statement has an alert in it, and the alert is coming up twice too. I had it in an || (or) statements, and it was doing the same thing. I added a an alert and only one of them is coming up as true. In any case, I added an else statement as you suggested, and it did not make a difference.

Comment: @Shanimal if I click on it once, the alert does not fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the number of times jQuery and the Unobtrusive scripts are added in your html?  I had an issue in a previous project where one of these was duplicated and caused a double post.

Comment: you are right. That what was causing the script to execute twice.

Comment: Now I am getting a null exception. It appears that the parent controller is being called before the child controller. However, I need the opposite to happen. The child controller should be called first and then the parent controller.

Comment: what are you referring to as the parent and child controllers?

Comment: There is a StudentPage Controller that has a StudentPage View. The studentpage view is where I am opening the popup window. When I refer to the parent controller, I mean the StudentPage Controller. The child controller is the StudentInfo controller and StudentInfo  view that mainly handle the logic for the popup window.